# How can I see Ubuntu file system, installed on SDcard, FROM Android

Tags: dual-boot, android

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32bit bootable on my SD card (16GB) giving 6GB for Ubuntu (4 for documents), 10 to Android (FAT32 - boot flags).

How can I open Ubuntu files from Android device?

Ubuntu folder to access : `/home/desktop/download`

I have rooted HTC sensation.

Answer (score -1):

i have a nexus 4  and i'm not sure if this works for sensation but give it a try. open ES file explorer(or any file explorer that can gain root), give it root permissions. for nexus 4 user data is located at:  /data/user-data/phablet/